# Pagination not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, pagination

I have a list and I display only 10 entries per page, I use a pagination to go to the next, previous, first or last page.

I use javascript to change page but it is not working on iOS (working everywhere else) :

```
function goToPage(pgNumber) {
  $('input[name="path"]').val("/ExtranetEuro/ReportingUnifieBuilder.do?TABLE_ID=_UNIFIE_ID");
  $('input[name="indexSort_UNIFIE_ID').val('0');
  $('input[name="sort_UNIFIE_ID').val('up');
  $('input[name="fldParam_UNIFIE_ID').val(pgNumber);
  $("#filtres").submit();
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="text-center" name="pagination">
<button onclick="goToPage(2);" style="padding:15px; margin-top:25px" type="button">CLICK CLICK</button>
</div>
```

I also tried using

```
<a href="javascript:goToPage(2)"></a>
```

but I have the same problem

Comment: have you alerted something in the function? whether the control goes over there or not?

Comment: yeah, the alert is working on Safari desktop but not on iphone

Comment: Try double click(first click for hover)

Comment: Thanks, double clicking trigger the alert (I put it at the beginning of my goToPage function) but i'm still not changing page